# Responsive centering and cropping a non-background image

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, image-resizing

I'm creating a responsive photo&text slider that scales a horizontal image with the outer wrapper for large window sizes and then uses overflow:hidden with negative margin ( (wrapperWidth - imageWidth)/2 ) and image max-width of 400% for smaller window sizes. This allows to display a centrally cropped portrait image.

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><a href=""><img alt="" src="image.jpg"/></a> 
        <div class="caption">
           <h2><a href="">Large Caption</a></h2>
           <p><a href="">Small Caption</a></p>
        </div>  
    </li>
    etc.etc.
</div>

.slider .slides li{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider .slides img{
    max-width: 400%;
}
etc.


$(window).resize(function(){
    var container = $('.slider');
    imageWidth =container.find('.slides img').width();
    wrapperWidth =container.find('.slides').width();
    margin = (wrapperWidth - imageWidth) / 2;
    container.find('.slides img').css('margin-left', margin)
});
```

**The Question**

The setup works great on page loads but when resizing the browser window, Jquery seems to loose the image width (returns 0) at random times while still calculating the wrapper width properly.  This then calculates an incorrect margin value and does not center the image.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: it could be because container.find('.slides img') can return an array, try something like container.find('.slides img:eq(0)')

Answer (score 0):

I would think that this will work. I have not tested:

```
$(function() {
$(window).on("resize", function()
    {
        var container = $(".slider");
        imageWidth =container.find(".slides img:eq(0)").width();
        wrapperWidth =container.find(".slides").width();
        margin = (wrapperWidth - imageWidth) / 2;
        container.find(".slides img").css({"margin-left": margin})
    });
});
```